# Published date/datetime not correctly displayed on frontend in Typo3

Tags: html, datetime, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I am trying out Typo3 on a demosite on my own hosting environment. I installed the news extension and mentioned that everytime I set the date of content it gets rendered incorrect. I set the date in the typo3 backend. I am using typo3 8.7.20 and the latest stable news extension (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/news/). A news article or just a simple heading looks like this:

(https://ibb.co/YpwqK2p)

The HTML for the part under the first news entry looks like this:

(https://ibb.co/C0D8fjf)

I doublechecked all my system configurations or database entries for errors but everything seems to work fine. I can't figure out what leads to this error.

Another problem seems to be that news articles can't be found if I click on them for a detailed view. Maybe this is also related to the date problem? I have a listview and a detailed view of the news extension configured in my backend. I just see this error on a blank page:

```
The news record is not available anymore.
```

I found out that the html actually looks like this:

```
<p class="">&lt;time datetime="2019-01-04"&gt;</p>
```

So there seems to be an issue with the charset I guess?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a charset problem, but a rendering one.

you do not mention the version of the news extension you use. I assume you use an outdated version as this kind of error probably will be corrected very soon if it is in the original templates, which you probably use.

it looks like the `time` tag is generated with php (maybe typoscript) and the fluid-variable contains ready made HTML.
since 8 LTS all fluid-variables are escaped by default. if you want unescaped content like here you need to use the `f:format.raw` view helper.

either the problem might be solved with an update of `EXT:news` or you might need to override the fluid template (probably a partial) with a copy where you insert the viewhelper.
look for the place in your fluid templates and add the view helper. either

```
<p class=""><f:format.raw>{timetag}</f:format.raw></p>
```

or

```
<p class="">{timetag->f:format.raw()}</p>
```

(I don't know the name of the fluid-variable and used `timetag`)